# How to make this available inside render function

Tags: reactjs

This is my React component:

```react
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    };
    this.showChart = this.showChart.bind(this)
}

showChart() {
    console.log('test')
}

render() {

    {this.showChart} //throws error that, this is undefined

    return () (
        {this.showChart} //prints test
    )
}
```

Now, if I want to call the function from `render()` but outside `return()` what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Component syntax is incorrect at a few places. `this` is available inside render.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    };
    this.showChart = this.showChart.bind(this)
}

showChart() {
    console.log('test')
}

render() {

  this.showChart() 

  return ( 
      <div>{this.showChart()}</div> 
  )

}
```

**EDIT:**

You can also work with arrow functions to bind said functions to your component. By doing this, you don't have to `bind` every function. It looks a lot cleaner:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    };
}

showChart = () => {
    console.log('test')
}

render() {

  this.showChart() 

  return ( 
      <div>{this.showChart()}</div> 
  )

}
```

Comment: Happy that it helped you

Answer (score 0):

replace {this.showChart} with this.showChart()inside the render function. So your new code should be

```
render(){
 this.showChart();

 return(
      {this.showChart}      
);
}
```